# Is it possible to add superscript in essential js chart for axis titles/labels?

Tags: ej2-syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I made a graph (chart) with essential js related to pressure and I need the x-axis label to be superscript like this :

m<sup>3</sup>/s

I tried adding the `<sup>` tag in the title text value, but it just prints the tag and doesn't work as intended. I couldn't find anything in the docs as well.

Is there a way to do this or essential js doesn't support this?